# freemarker error, undefined Expression

Tags: html, freemarker

i want to print a matrix with ftl code, so  i have two lists activities and skills 
an activities containt a list of competence so if activities(i) containt the skills(i) i set x in the right position in matrix
 this my code

```
 <div id="menu" class="one whole">
<div class="one sixth">a\c</div>
[#list 1..y as i]
<div class="one sixth">c${i}</div>
[/#list]

[#list 1..x as ss]
<div class="one sixth">a${ss}</div>
   [#assign l = activities[ss].getCompetences()?size]
   [#if l > 0]
   [#assign liste = activities[ss].getCompetences()]
   <li><a href="?3.0.1.0">${activities[16].getCompetences()[1].name}</a></li>
   <li><a href="?3.0.1.0">${activities[16].getCompetences()[0].name}</a></li>
 <li><a href="?3.0.1.0">${activities[17].getCompetences()[1].name}</a></li>
 <li><a href="?3.0.1.0">${activities[17].getCompetences()[0].name}</a></li>

            [#list 1..y as j]
            [#assign vrai = 0]
            [#assign x2 = '${skills[j].name}']
            [#assign l = activities[ss].getCompetences()?size]
                [#list 0..l as element]

                [#assign x1 = '${activities[ss].getCompetences()  [element].name}']

                     [#if x1 == x2]
                     [#assign vrai = vrai+1]
                     [/#if]
                [/#list]
                [#if vrai > 0]      
                     <div class="one sixth">X</div>
                [#else]
                     <div class="one sixth">000</div>  
                [/#if]
             [/#list]
    [#else]
       [#list 1..y as j]
       <div class="one sixth">000</div>
       [/#list]     
     [/#if]    
   [/#list]
   </div>
```

the error is Caused by: freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression activities[ss].getCompetences()[element] is undefined on line 25,([#assign x1 = '${activities[ss].getCompetences()[element].name}'])

but this expression is correct here (a)  :

${activities[16].getCompetences()[1].name}

(b)  :

${activities[16].getCompetences()[0].name}

i used (a) and (b) just for testing.

can someone find what is the problem.

```
        model.put("activities", activities);
    model.put("skills", skills);
    model.put("x", x);
    model.put("y", y);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the message, `a[ss]` is undefined. So one possibility is that you have not set `a` in the freemarker model.  Another possibility is that your `a` list is zero based, not one based. You are iterating 1..x.

Other than that, you have not provided enough info. Consider providing the full output of the freemarker exception, and more clearly explain what it is that 'a' and `x` contain.

Comment: a and x exist, x it the size of a

Comment: but the problem is how can i extract  elements from a and  the elements for a's elements.

Comment: what is `a`? Is it a an array? A List? Is it zero based? If so, why not use `[#list a as aElement]` instead of an index loop?  If you continue to use an index loop, then perhaps `[#list 0..(x-1) as ss]`. Again, you have not provided enough info for someone to be able to help.

Comment: i modified my code but i couldn't solve all problems

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with the `..` operator. Its right hand operand is interpreted as inclusive, so with `0..length` you code will fail. And if you try to write `0..(length-1)`, that will also fail if the `length` is 0, as it will be `[-1, 0]` then.

Also, if you list indexes only to do `someList[theIndex]` later, you are doing something wrong. You should then list the list items instead, and then if you need the index, use `itemName_index` (see http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html#ref.directive.list).

"Expression activities[ss].getCompetences()[element]" means that your index is out of range, or that there's a `null` in the list at the given index.